# How to update the color of (the state of) the cell during resize in mxgraph?

Tags: mxgraph

I want to change the color of a state of a cell during resize of the cell.
To achieve this, I have added the following code to mxVertexHandler.prototype.updateLivePreview:

```
mxVertexHandler.prototype.updateLivePreview = function (me) {
 ...
 this.state.x = this.bounds.x;
 this.state.y = this.bounds.y;
 this.state.origin = new mxPoint(this.state.x / scale - tr.x, this.state.y / scale - tr.y);
 this.state.width = this.bounds.width;
 this.state.height = this.bounds.height;
 ...
 this.state.shape.fill = "#CCCCCC";
 this.state.shape.fillOpacity = 30;
 ...
}
```

What happens is that this code changes the opacity of the cell while resized, but does **not** change the fill color.
How can I cange the fill color too?

Thanks,

-- Jaap

Comment: Have you tried `graph.setCellStyles(mxConstants.STYLE_FILLCOLOR, 'black', [cell]);` ?

Answer (score 0):

No, that does not work either.
BTW, I thought that temporal changes, e.g. during a resize, should go via the state.

I do not understand why fillOpacity (and other properties) works, and fill not. It seems that the fill is overwritten somewhere else (e.g. after calling updateLivePreview), but I can not figure out where.